# Mistake in the code. Scikit-image, Spyder

Tags: python, scikit-image

I got this warning but I cannot fix it. Code works.

`Warning: Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0, 1]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.`

```
from skimage.io import imread, imshow, imsave 

img_grey = imread('C:/Lawn.png', as_gray=True)
imsave('Lawn22.png', img_grey)

img = imread('C:/Lawn.png')
imshow(img)
```

Comment: Have you been able to debug which specific line causes the warning?

Comment: Thank. If I delete ```imsave('Lawn22.png', img_grey)``` the code works correctly. But I need this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need after reading image convert `float64 to type uint8` like below for removing this warning message with this code:

```
img_grey = img_grey / img_grey.max() #normalizes img_grey in range 0 - 255
img_grey = 255 * img_grey
img_grey = img_grey.astype(np.uint8)
```

whole code without warning message:

```
from skimage.io import imread, imshow, imsave 
img_grey = imread('C:/Lawn.png', as_gray=True)

# convert image to uint8
img_grey = img_grey / img_grey.max() #normalizes img_grey in range 0 - 255
img_grey = 255 * img_grey
img_grey = img_grey.astype(np.uint8)


imsave('Lawn22.png', img_grey)
img = imread('C:/Lawn.png')
imshow(img_grey)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain me? What can I use in skikit-image to get file size (bytes), image size (pixels), color mode, the number of bits per pixel. I looked for it but everything that I found is .shape, .size, .max, .min

Comment: @aleksandr skimage don't have these features. you need your self get this items, better is create a new question and top user can help you very much. explain what you want here exist very good user with high experience.